# Is it possible to run NUnit 2.5.3 tests in Gallio?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, gallio

When I try to run NUnit tests in Gallio I get this:

> Detected a probable test framework assembly version mismatch.
>   Referenced test frameworks: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.3.9345, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'.
>   Supported test frameworks: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.0-2.5.2.65535', 'nunit.framework, Version=2.4.8.0-2.4.8.65535'.

I use Gallio v3.1 build 397.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not tested but it will probably work.  Try editing the Gallio.NUnitAdapter.plugin file for v2.5 and specify the new version.

Edit: Actually, after seeing this question I just made the change in trunk.  Assuming it just works then NUnit v2.5.3 should be supported in Gallio v3.2 build 385 or newer.

Comment: Worked fine! As long as you don't do what I did and copy the .plugin file in the same folder which leads to Gallio not starting... :)
Thanks!

Comment: Just downloaded 3.2.422 and had the same problem.  Changing components/component/traits/frameworkAssemblies (in the plugin file) to reference 2.5.3 instead of 2.5.0 did the trick.